# How to access grid files by coordinate args in a bash script?

Tags: bash, matrix, geolocation, grid

I have a huge [ESRI Grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esri_grid) file with space separated data. To simplify this question, I'll use an example file `elevation.asc` with 5x5 values.

The header of my `elevation.asc` contains some additional information about the data, including the starting coordinates (latitude, longitude) of the first value. The complete file looks like that:

```
ncols         5
nrows         5
xllcorner     3356385.137
yllcorner     5800799.818
cellsize      1.0
NODATA_value  -9999
31.11266 31.03987 31.15038 30.98865 30.96297
29.65054 29.65345 29.65598 29.60781 29.61685
29.70712 29.66978 29.73194 29.83858 29.87868
29.54893 29.60815 29.62812 29.66953 29.70786
29.55878 29.55927 29.58562 29.66112 29.79232
```

Now my question is, how to access the elevation data in this file by given coordinates using a `bash` script?

I want to call my script and yield the first data value like this `usage: myscript.sh {file} {x} {y}`:

```
 $ ./myscript.sh elevation.asc 3356385.137 5800799.818
31.11266
```

Or:

```
 $ ./myscript.sh elevation.asc 3356387.137 5800803.818
29.58562
```

Now, what have I tried so far? I was playing around with `while` loops iterating throug x and y coordinates and `awk` to parse the header and `bc` to do some float point calculation. But I'm kind of lost now how to proceed. This is what I got:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
E_BADARGS=65
E_NOINPUT=66
N_ARGS=3

# Checks for proper number of command line args.
if [ $# -ne $N_ARGS ] ; then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` {input.file} {x} {y}"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi

# Checks for proper input file.
INPUT=$1
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit $E_NOINPUT; }

# Parses file header info.
cols=$(awk '$1 == "ncols" { print $2 }' $INPUT)
rows=$(awk '$1 == "nrows" { print $2 }' $INPUT)
x11=$(awk '$1 == "xllcorner" { print $2 }' $INPUT)
y11=$(awk '$1 == "yllcorner" { print $2 }' $INPUT)
size=$(awk '$1 == "cellsize" { print $2 }' $INPUT)
nodata=$(awk '$1 == "NODATA_value" { print $2 }' $INPUT)

# Calculates maximum coordinates.
xpp=$(bc <<< "$x11+$cols-1")
ypp=$(bc <<< "$y11+$rows-1")

# Gets requested coordinates from args.
X=$2
Y=$3

### What now?
```

But yeah, what now? I can iterate through the whole raster using `while` loops to find out the position of the coordinates but then I notice all I did was finding the input coordinates not the stored data value.

```
# Iterates through the whole raster.
while [ $(echo "$y11 < $ypp" | bc) == 1 ] ; do
  while [ $(echo "$x11 < $xpp" | bc) == 1 ] ; do
    if [ $X == $x11 ] && [ $Y == $y11 ] ; then
      ### What now?
    fi
    x11=$(bc <<< "$x11+$size")
  done
  y11=$(bc <<< "$y11+$size")
done
```

I don't know how to proceed. How to access the elevation data using a bash script?

---

#### Update: Clarifications

The given 5x5 matrix on top of this question is a data plot representing a digital elevation model. Each value means *meters above sea level*.

**Input and Output**: I call my script with three arguments: the filename, the latitude coordinate (x) and the longitude coordinate (y). Like that:

```
 $ ./myscript.sh elevation.asc 3356385.137 5800799.818
```

Now in the header is defined the dataset starts in the upper left corner (the first coordinate) at the coordinates `xllcorner=3356385.137` and `yllcorner=5800799.818`. So calling the script with this two coordinates should yield the first elavation data (z) in the upper left corner of the 5x5 matrix which is `z=31.11266`. `size` is the size of steps between 2 fields of data in x- and y-direction *in meters*. So calling this:

```
 $ ./myscript.sh elevation.asc 3356387.137 5800803.818
```

... means going two steps in x- and 4 steps in y-direction which yields `z=29.58562`. Simply count it out in the matrix.

It would be more simple if `xllcorner` and `yllcorner` would be `0` but that's not the case.

Comment: Don't use bash, it will only frustrate you and annoy the computer. Since you already know awk rudiments, try Perl; this is the kind of task it was designed for.

Comment: And by "annoy the computer" I mean "will take a *really* long time" on your "huge file".

Comment: +1 for a model question. It's all there, data, expected output, and gasp,code! One thing.., so the data format repeats over and over again in 1 file? And you have no control over how this file is presented to you? If I felt really constrained to only cmd-line technology, I think this could be done in awk and would think about flattening the data so each set is on one line. Assuming this isn't really a one-off and throw away task, I would put the data into a database. A basic note: any use of `$(... anything ..)` is creating another process and going to slow things down dramatically. Good luck.

Comment: +1 on the question. Can you please explain how `3356385.137 5800799.818` returns value of `31.11266` and `3356387.137 5800803.818` returns `29.58562`

Comment: @Jaypal think of the data matrix as a coordinate system. the first data in the upper left corner has the (x, y, z) values (3356385.137, 5800799.818, 31.11266) and analogue: (3356387.137, 5800803.818, 29.58562) is the data-tripple in the last row in the middle. got it? xllcorner and yllcorner is the starting-coordinates and at the upper left and size is the size of the steps to increase from x0 to x1 to x2 and y0 to y1 to y2 and so on, in this case +1.0.

Comment: Need more info/examples on i/p and the o/p of your problem !!

Comment: @Chronicles tried to improve the input and output description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a perl solution.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use autodie;
use List::MoreUtils qw(any);

my $data_file = shift;
my %metadata;
my @data;

open my $fh, '<', $data_file;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @F = split;
    if (any {$F[0] eq $_} qw(ncols nrows xllcorner yllcorner cellsize NODATA_value)) {
        $metadata{$F[0]} = $F[1];
    }
    else {
        push @data, \@F;
    }
}
close $fh;

while (@ARGV) {
    my $x = shift;
    my $y = shift;
    my $x_delta = int(($x - $metadata{xllcorner}) / $metadata{cellsize});
    my $y_delta = int(($y - $metadata{yllcorner}) / $metadata{cellsize});
    if ($x_delta < 0 or $y_delta < 0 or not defined $data[$y_delta][$x_delta]) {
        say $metadata{NODATA_value};
    }
    else {
        say $data[$y_delta][$x_delta];
    }
}
```

Since reading all the data will probably be expensive, you should be able to pass in several pairs of coordinates at one time: that's the while loop consuming @ARGV. This gives you:

```
$ perl esri.pl elevation.asc 0 0 3356385.137 5800799.818 3356387.137 5800803.818
-9999
31.11266
29.58562
```

Comment: This is a very nice and usefull script, I just tested it. But there seems to be a huge issue with memory. On a 2.6GB grid file I need around [26GB](http://i.imagebanana.com/img/bujuqbav/Screenshot1.png) main memory. How's that?

Comment: In addition, my shell script needs 7 seconds for one yielded data value and your perl script needs around 2 minutes. Starting with 18 or more requested values your script will be more time-efficient than mine because your script's time is independent from number of input args. The huge memory consumption will be an issue if used on machines with lower capacities available. Any ideas?

Comment: With this much data, you'll greatly benefit from using a real database.

Comment: BTW, you'll save *some* memory by saving the file as an array of lines, not an array of arrays, and only splitting the line when you need to access the x-coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, figured out my self. It was pretty simple adding only 3 lines to the code above:

```
# Calculates the line number and column.
LINE=$(bc <<< "scale=0;($Y-$y11+7)/1")
COLN=$(bc <<< "scale=0;($X-$x11+1)/1")

# Prints the Z Coordinates at X=COLN and Y=LINE
awk -v line=$LINE 'NR == line { print $0 }' $INPUT  | cut -f $COLN -d " "
```

Simply calculate the position of the elevation data value by substracting the entered `$X` and `$Y` by the starting coordinate `x11` and `y11` like written above.

The whole working code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=$1

# Parses starting coordinates.
x11=$(awk '$1 == "xllcorner" { print $2 }' $INPUT)
y11=$(awk '$1 == "yllcorner" { print $2 }' $INPUT)

# Gets requested coordinates from args.
X=$2
Y=$3

# Calculates the line number and column.
LINE=$(bc <<< "scale=0;($Y-$y11+7)/1")
COLN=$(bc <<< "scale=0;($X-$x11+1)/1")

# Prints the Z Coordinates at X=COLN and Y=LINE
awk -v line=$LINE 'NR == line { print $0 }' $INPUT  | cut -f $COLN -d " "
```

Arguments are: `{file} {x} {y}`
Example usage: `./myscript.sh elevation.asc 3356387.137 5800803.818`